# Choice Stack Between Meteor, Ionic 2, Firebase

Tags: angular, meteor, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm brand new to coding (still consoliding my JS) and i have a project for a webiste + mobile app to help people with their diet. It will have a database with lots of recipe and people will be able to put their needs, the application will propose them list of groceries and recipe to suit their needs. The point is not to discuss the application, i know there is a lot out here about that.

What i would like to know is which solution will best suits my needs. I read about angular2 for the web application and ionic 2 for the mobile part, and i was planning to use firebase for the database.

BUT i recently learned that something called Meteor is doing all of this in one place.

I post this on stack to be sure that i understand correctly, so i'm wright or totally wrong ?

Thank you in advance for your help and i whish you all a good day !

Comment: This question is way to vague and is asking for an opinion or recommendation about a programming tool. This forum is for programming questions and yes, it is for *specifically discussing an issue within your application code*. Craft some code and when you get stuck post it and your Firebase structure (as text please, no images) so we can help. By the way, only you can answer your own question since only you knows the scope of your project.

Comment: Thank you @Jay , for your answer and time. I understand your answer, i just wanted to know the opinion of people who might have used both of the solution i've listed, and the pros and cons of each one. Because i'm new, i don't have the experience for knowing that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Meteor uses MongoDB as the primary database. If you are set on Firebase as your DB, then Meteor will not help you there (though you should be able to use it via Apollo Stack, but that is more advance stuff).
If realtime and desktop/mobile clients is your goal then yes Meteor has all of that pretty much out of the box (not to mention great account management).

As a Meteor developer I'm biased for Meteor. My suggestion is try tutorials for all of your options and then try a bit on your own and then make your decision to what feels better.
With Meteor you can use Angular or React (or Blaze) for your frontend and build Cordova apps at the same time as your browser implementation. There is also an official guide for the bit advance stuff: https://guide.meteor.com/

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look at the guide and try some small feature to see if it's suits my need. If not i will only learn more from meteor which is not a bad thing.

I just wanted to avoid to start on everything and see what's best, but apparently i will have to !